How to Decode Hex Values from a GPS Tracker Using PHP (GT06 Protocol)
I'm working on decoding hex values from a GPS tracker that I believe uses the GT06 protocol in PHP. I wrote the following code to process the location update, but I'm getting incorrect location details.
protected function processLocationUpdate($hexData)
{
    if (strlen($hexData) >= 34) {
        $latitudeHex = substr($hexData, 18, 6);
        $longitudeHex = substr($hexData, 24, 8);

        $latitude = hexdec($latitudeHex) / 1000000;
        $longitude = hexdec($longitudeHex);
        if ($longitude >= 0x80000000) {
            $longitude -= 0x100000000;
        }
        $longitude /= 1000000;

        $this->info("GPS Location - Latitude: " . $latitude . ", Longitude: " . $longitude);
        $this->info("Raw location data (hex): " . $latitudeHex . " " . $longitudeHex);
    } else {
        $this->error("Received message does not contain enough data for a location update.");
    }
}

Here are the raw payloads I'm receiving from the GPS tracker:
Raw payload: 78780a13040602000102c51db60d0a
Raw payload: 7878222204010101121dc000a39db508a59d9c000400019d01f956003bda00000002c6b3280d0a

I also looked at this GitHub script but couldn’t fully understand the decoding process. I even tried hiring freelancers, but they couldn't help either and suggested that the protocol might be wrong.
Could someone please help me figure out how to properly decode these hex values, or clarify if there’s something wrong with the protocol I'm using? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
I wrote a PHP function to decode hex values from the GPS tracker based on the GT06 protocol. I expected to extract the correct latitude and longitude values from the raw payloads I received. However, the results are consistently incorrect, showing wrong location details. I also reviewed a GitHub script for similar decoding but couldn’t understand how it worked. I attempted to hire freelancers for assistance, but they couldn’t resolve the issue, suggesting that there might be a problem with the protocol I’m using.

Was the Github script you mention this one? https://github.com/vondraussen/gt06/blob/master/gt06.js

Presumably you've looked at the protocol specification document? https://www.traccar.org/protocol/5023-gt06/GT06_GPS_Tracker_Communication_Protocol_v1.8.1.pdf - although that second raw payload doesn't seem to conform to the document, on first reading.
